# Mysql query question

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have 2 tables:

> Customer: customerid - int,
>   pri-key,auto fname - varchar sname
>   -varchar housenum - varchar street -varchar
>
> Items: itemid - int,pri-key,auto type -
>   varchar collectiondate - date
>   releasedate - date customerid - int

**EDIT** 
I need a query which will get me all items that have a releasedate of 3 days into the future, including today

i.e The query should return customerid,fname,sname,street,housenum,type,releasedate for all items which have releasedate of today or 3 days into the future.e.g, if todays date was 2010-12-24, and an item has release date of 2010-12-25 then it would be returned ion the query.

The idea is that if an item is due for release (today or 3 days ahead of today) then it will show this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  c.customerid, c.fname, c.sname, c.street, c.housenum, i.type, i.releasedate
FROM    items i
JOIN    customers c
ON      c.customerid = i.customerid
WHERE   i.releasedate >= CURDATE()
        AND i.releasedate < CURDATE() + INTERVAL `4` DAY
```

Note the use of two comparisons (strict and loose) instead of `BETWEEN`, and `4` days instead of `3`.

This means that if you run this query on `Jan 1st`, it will return you the items with release date greater or equal than `Jan 1st`, but strictly less that `Jan 5th`.

This means that any record with date part of `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` of `January` will make it to your query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT c.customerid, c.fname, c.sname, c.street, c.housenum, i.type, i.releasedate 
FROM Items i JOIN Customer c ON i.customerid  = c.customerid 
WHERE i.releasedate BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND NOW()
```

Comment: If you want to get from 3 days prior to the current **date** (today 12:00 AM) use `CURDATE()` instead of `NOW()`

Comment: Sorry I have edited my post, I need all items which have a releasedate between TODAYs date and 3 days ahead of today. I edited your query so that it is .. BETWEEN NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY AND NOW() ... but it returns no rows :s

Comment: Switch it to `BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY `, the lower part must come first